# Encoding filenames made by php with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, apache, unix, filenames

When I upload a file named æøåtest.mp3 via filezilla (on Win7) to a unix server, and refresh the filezilla window, the file changes to Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥test.mp3.
But it works fine when accessing the file as æøåtest.mp3 with browser

When I upload the same file with php (move_uploaded_file, on Apache, same unix server) and test in browser, the server responds: "%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5test.mp3 not found".
Then I look in filezilla, and the file is there, shown as æøåtest.mp3

Hmmm, all this encoding stuff is very confusing to me.. url_encoding, url_decoding, url_rawdecoding, iso, utf8, etc.
How do I get about this?

Should I disallow/remove any foreign characters in filenames, other than plain english?

Comment: you can always rename the file once you use move_upload_file..

Comment: You can specify the character encoding for any given server connection within Filezilla under Site Manager -> pick server -> Charset.   Also, I believe apache defaults to ISO-8859-1 which could account for the URL issue.  Consider changing to UTF-8;  and make sure all your pages are encoded utf-8.